# org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [admin_pkey];

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I am able to insert data successfuly into mysql database, now I am switching my database into postgresql and I am having this challenge

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [admin_pkey]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: 
could not execute statement
```

I have ensured a generation_auto annotation to my id column and still the error persists, this is my class mappings

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(unique = false, nullable = false)
    private Date date;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

Comment: Can you give more information about query you tried to executed or schema

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing your database then accordingly you should also change the hibernate configuration XML.
Here goes the `hibernate.cfg.xml` :

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>

        <property name="connection_pool_size">1</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

       <mapping class="org.sample"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```